# Test ads showing but original ads not showing in phonegap build app in Google admob

Tags: android, cordova, admob

i have created a simple app in Phonegap build ,and integrated and linked the app with Google admob ,when i test the app in test ads mode it showing the test ads ,but as i published the app on google play it doesn't showing original ads .

My Code For Preparing  ads

`var admobid = {};`
`if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {`
    `admobid = { // for Android`
        `banner: 'ca-app-pub-5584769932279177/2482584044',`
        `interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-5584769932279177/1005850846'`
    `};`
`} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {`
    `admobid = { // for iOS`
        `banner: '',`
        `interstitial: ''`
    `};`
`} else {`
    `admobid = { // for Windows Phone`
        `banner: '',`
        `interstitial: ''`
    `};`
`}`

`function initApp() {`
    `if (AdMob) {`
        
        `AdMob.setOptions({` 
            `bgColor: 'black', // color name, or '#RRGGBB'` 
       `});`

`AdMob.createBanner({` 
     `adId : admobid.banner,`
      `position : AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,`
       `autoShow : true`
      `});`
      `}`
      `if(AdMob){`
         `AdMob.prepareInterstitial({`
         `adId:admobid.interstitial,`
         `autoShow:false`
      `}`
 `);`
 `}`
 `}`

`if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {`
    `document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);`
`} else {`
    `initApp();`
`}`

Code for Showing Interstitial Ads

`window.onload=function(){`

`window.onbeforeunload = function(){`
              `if(AdMob)`
               `AdMob.showInterstitial();`
        `};`
`}`

And also included the following lines in my config file

`<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />`
`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" source="npm" />`

Comment: Generally this happens because no ads is available in that region where you are testing, if it is displaying test ads it will show the ads if available

Comment: Please wait it will take time to show.

Comment: it means there is no problem in my coding . as test ads are showing very well

Comment: if test ad is showing then there is no problem in code.

Comment: do i need to add Facebook or other companies ads separately or it will included automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wait check and approve (up to 2 days).

Answer (score 0):

Generally this happens because no ads is available in that region where you are testing, if it is displaying test ads it will show the ads if available.
your Code is correct if it is showing the Test ads or the ads are taking time to load